# Why is "I find this article is interesting" grammatically incorrect?

Tags: meaning, usage

1. I believe that you are a good person.
2. I believe you are a good person.
3. I find that this article is very interesting.
4. I find this article is interesting.
5. I find this article interesting.

I know that sentence number 4 is incorrect but can you give a grammatical explanation why? Why can't we lose the "that" like in sentences 1 and 2. If any of the rest of the sentences is incorrect please point it out. Thanks.

Comment: I think the word ***that*** is ALWAYS optional in contexts like *I believe [that] you are good*, and the same NORMALLY applies to ***to be*** in the alternative (subjunctive) phrasing *I believe you [to be] good*. But note that there's no obvious or fixed rule regarding which verbs are idiomatic for that second phrasing. That's to say, I don't think there's any clearly-defined rule explaining why we don't normally say *I **suspect** you [to be] good*, but we *can* quite easily say [*I **think** him dishonest.*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+think+him+dishonest%22)

Comment: I almost wholly agree with FumbleFingers, yet I think the example spoiled it. I don't think it's fair to compare "I suspect you [to be]…" with "I think him…"

Wouldn't the fair comparison be "I suspect you [to be]…" with "I think him [to be]…"

Most obviously, the difference between "I believe you are…" and "I believe that you are…" is one of emphasis, which pretty-much always depends on what follows…

Answer (score 5):

Sentence 4 is perfectly good, but less common than 5.

As you surmise, 4 is similar to 3, and equivalent to *I find that this article is interesting*, which has a different meaning from 5.

4 means "I discover that this article is interesting" whereas 5 means "I judge or experience this article as interesting". They might be said in the same circumstances, but they are expressing different mental processes.

Comment: +1 A nuanced answer. _Expressing different mental states_ : I liked this bit. @Colin Fine.